# Width of table and text wrapping using tabularx, cline, multicolumn

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, cline

I am having problems making a table fit my page. I have used the `tabularx` environment and the `\linewidth` parameter, which successfully shortens the width of the `\cline`, but doesn't force the text to wrap so the table still falls off the page. Ideally, I'd like the headings '(t, n, d)-RTS' and 'Underlying (m, d, 1)-Schemes' to wrap and make the table slightly slimmer. Please see below for an example.

Any help would be appreciated. I've never had any issues with making `tabularx` and `\linewidth` work, but don't tend to use `\multicolumn` that often... is `tabularx` conflicting with `\multicolumn` somehow?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | l l | l l l | l  l l | }
\cline{2-9}
                       & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{Combinatorial Schemes [1] }         & \multicolumn{3}{ l | }{MBR Schemes [2]}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(t, n, d)-$RTS }  &Underlying  $(m, d, 1)-$ Schemes     & $n$ & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\ \cline{1-9} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(9, 3, 1)$    & $6 \le n \le 12$  & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.1111$       & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(15, 3, 1)$    & $10 \le n \le 35$ & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.2222$      & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(21, 3, 1)$    & $14 \le n \le 70$ & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.3333$       & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your `tabularx` has no `X` columns, so can not work. But you do npt want line breaking here so you would be better to use `tabular` than `tabularx`

Comment: Thank you. What are X columns sorry? I have replaced the \tabular line with "\begin{tabular}{p{0.1cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{1cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}} ", which definitely helps, but no matter how small I make the first column, the '(t, n, d)-RTS' does not seem to wrap at all.

Comment: Also, by replacing the line with "\begin{tabular}{p{0.1cm} | p{1.7cm}p{2.3cm} | p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{1cm} | p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm} |}", everything fits kind of okay, but on the right, the 'MBR Schemes [2]' does not wrap either.

Comment: you must have seen somewhere some documentation that told you that `tabularx` existed? The only feature `tabularx` adds is a new column type `X` for variable width columns, so any documentation that tells you about `tabularx` should have mentioned `X`. (see `texdoc tabularx` for the main package documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never use `tabularx` for such a table, also in $n$-foo  the `-` should be a text hyphen, not a minus.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l l | l l l | l  l l | }
\cline{2-9}
       & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\hd{Combinatorial Schemes\\{}[1]}}         & 
\multicolumn{3}{ c | }{\hd{MBR Schemes\\{}[2]}}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\hd{$(t, n, d)$-\\RTS} }  &
\hd{Underlying\\$(m, d, 1)$-\\Schemes}     & $n$ & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\ \cline{1-9} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(9, 3, 1)$    & $6 \le n \le 12$  & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.1111$       & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(15, 3, 1)$    & $10 \le n \le 35$ & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.2222$      & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$(2, n, 3)$}  & $(21, 3, 1)$    & $14 \le n \le 70$ & $1/2$   & $3/2$   & $0.3333$       & $2/3$    & $3/2$     & $1$    \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```